# How to clear Input Text Box field on click of "Discard Changes Button" & also retain the value of Input Box that is coming from a service

Tags: angularjs

This is something conceptual.
I have a Input text box ---> Name:"**With some name for example Mike(in text box)**" that is coming from a service.
I have **Discard Changes Button**.
On editing the name,the button gets enabled but when I click on discard changes button :

- I want to discard the current changes of input box and retain the
  value that was coming from service.
- I tried and made the model null but it makes the complete input box
  blank.

Please Help.
Thanks

Comment: You'll have to save the original values for your inputs in a separate set of variables so that you can reset the form as desired.

Comment: @Lex :Is there any method to reset the form because i just want for some fields.As values coming directly from  a service how will I bind to variables ? Can you please explain with an example ?

Comment: If you're asking is there an Angular method you can call that will automagically reset some of your inputs to their orginal values while leaving other inputs alone the answer is no.

Comment: call a function on button click and inside the function, assign the value you had in service to the `ng-model` attached to your input.

Answer (score 0):

When u first get data from service you can use angular.copy to store data that you get for the first time, and on discard changes click you can simply use that copied data.